# Sendgrid (Node JS) add contact to custom Marketing list

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm trying to add a contact to the marketing list with Sendgrid Node JS

```
 var request = require("request");

      var options = { method: 'PUT',
        url: 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts',
        headers: { authorization: 'Bearer myAPIKEY' },
        body: '{"contacts":[{"email": "myMail@gmail.com","unique_name":"myName"}]}' };

      request(options, function () {
      });
```

Everything works, but I would also like to add the contact to a specific list. I read the documentation and it says I need to add the id of the contact.

Where can I find that or How can I add a contact to a specific list?

Thank you!

Comment: where did you read that documentation

Comment: Thank you: i saw it here: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html#Add-Multiple-Recipients-to-a-List-POST

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I read the documentation, you can put a list ID within the body of the request,
like this:

```
"list_ids":["theidofyourlist"], "contacts" ....
```

Comment: Hey Karel where did you find this in the documentation?

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi it is noted in request body schema on page for Add or Update a Contact case in API documentation